# Python 2.7 list comprehension number pyramid

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to create the following number pyramid using nested list comprehension and string formatting.

```
1
2  4
3  6  9
4  8  12  16
5  10  15  20  25
6  12  18  24  30  36
7  14  21  28  35  40  47
```

I figured out how to create the pyramid using nested for loops but can't quite get it to work using list comprehension.  Here is my code:

```
for n in range(1,8):
    print
    for x in range(n):
        if x>0:
            print '%2d' % (n+(n*x)),
        else:
            print '%d' % n,
```

The same code using list comprehension gives me a syntax error:

```
rows = [
    '%2d' % (n+(n*x)), if x > 0 else '%d' % n,
    for n in range(1,8)
    for x in range(n)
]

print '\n' +'\n'.join(rows)
```

Any ideas on how to format the pyramid correctly using list comprehension?

Comment: Remove the commas: `['%2d' % (n+(n*x)) if x > 0 else '%d' % n for ...]`

Comment: Wouldn't you want `xrange` instead of `range`?  (I learned using Python 3, so I'm not 100% sure how Python 2 works.)

Comment: @RocketHazmat `xrange` is more efficient in Python 2 because it is lazily evaluated. However, the output size is so small in this example that I would prefer the more familiar `range`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `range` to build up each nested list, like so:

```
# Generation
result = [range(x, x**2 + 1, x) for x in range(1, 8)]

# Formatting
print('\n'.join(''.join(str(x).ljust(4) for x in row) for row in result))
```

**Output:**

```
1
2   4
3   6   9
4   8   12  16
5   10  15  20  25
6   12  18  24  30  36
7   14  21  28  35  42  49
```

Comment: An alternative might be to use `.rjust(4)` instead of tab.

Comment: @Elmex80s Edited to use `.ljust(4)` (the appearance *is* much nicer)

Answer (score 0):

You can `join` a list of lists (in this case, a generator of generators)  by newlines

```
print('\n'.join(' '.join(str(i*j) for j in range(1, i+1)) for i in range(1, n+1)))

#1
#2 4
#3 6 9
#4 8 12 16
#5 10 15 20 25
#6 12 18 24 30 36
#7 14 21 28 35 42 49
```

and if you want to have the list that creates it just do:

```
rows = [[i*j for j in range(1, i+1)] for i in range(1, n+1)]
```