# Build pyramid pattern using list comprehension in python?

Tags: python

Can anyone show me how to create half pyramid using list comprehension  ?

For example

```
*
**
***
```

I tried but did not succeed.

I am trying to convert following code into using dictionary comprehension

```
for i in range(0, n): 
    for j in range(0, i+1): 
        print("* ",end="") 
    print("\r")
```

Comment: What is a half-pyramid?

Comment: Please add your code and clarify, what your expected output is. "Half pyramid" is not well defined. Also: Please remove the `python-request` tag - it is not, what you think it is.

Comment: I am trying to convert following code into using dictionary comprehensive
for i in range(0, n):
     
       

        for j in range(0, i+1):
         
            print("* ",end="")

        print("\r")

Comment: Please [edit] your question. Also, this has nothing to do peewee or requests libraries, so don't spam the tags. Include what you have tried, and why you **want** to use list comprehension

Comment: You misunderstand the terminology. Comprehensive is not a thing in Python. It's comprehension

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for the correction

Comment: You aren't building a list, why would you use a list comprehension?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh following pattern is known as half pyramid
*
* * 
* * *
* * * *

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43662993/python-2-7-list-comprehension-number-pyramid

Comment: @akshaykasodariya don't use dictionary comprehensions to print things. That's not what they are for. They are for *building lists*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for the comments

Comment: @juanpa You can still join and print out the built list .  https://stackoverflow.com/a/43663178/2308683

Comment: @cricket_007 sure.

Comment: What have you tried, and how did it not work?

Answer (score 2):

Do not use list-comprehensions for side-effect (e.g. like printing). List comprehensions are for building lists. You *could* do something hacky, like this:

```
>>> junk = [print("\r") or [print("* ",end='') for j in range(0, i+1)] for i in range(0, n)]

*
* *
* * *
* * * *
* * * * *
* * * * * *
* * * * * * *
* * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * 
>>> junk
[[None], [None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]]
```

But you create a needless list of junk. *Don't do it.*

Comment: @cricket_007, by editing the output of this program you've hidden a flaw in the code in that it does not correctly produce a final newline.  It also prints an unnecesary blank line at the start due to a range beginning with zero instead of one.

Comment: You add a comment to the OP's post saying ***not*** to use comprehensions to print things.  You wrote an answer saying ***not*** to use comprehensions for side-effects like printing.  You then proceed to do exactly what you said not to do!  Shouldn't you be teaching by example?  (Or perhaps you are...)

Comment: @cdlane "You could do something hacky, like this: ... But you create a needless list of junk." But I've edited to reiterate the point, in case it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can create one line of *n* times the `*` symbol by using `join` on something similar to a list comprehension, namely a generator expression:

```
>>> ''.join('*' for _ in range(5))
'*****'
```

You can create output consisting of multiple lines by joining the individual lines with the newline character `'\n'` (as opposed to the empty string `''` like before):

```
>>> lines = '\n'.join(['hello', 'world'])
>>> lines
'hello\nworld'
>>> print(lines)
hello
world
```

I'll leave combining the two as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the `print()` statement out of the comprehension by returning something from the comprehension that will print as a pyramid:

```
n = 10

print(*['*' * i for i in range(1, n + 1)], sep='\n')
```

OUTPUT

```
> python3 test.py
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
**********
>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just write this, you no need to mention `sep='\n'`

```
n = 5

print('\n'.join(['*'*i for i in range(1,n+1)]))
```

> Note: You should always start your range from `1` to `n+1,` otherwise it will skip your first iteration.